# Javascript push into an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have been trying this fora a little while and cannot get it.

I have a piece of code to create an Array of an objects which is something like this :

```
var allUsers = new Array();
function addObjectToArray(userData){
    colorCode = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    userImage = "avatar"+Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+".jpg";
    newuserData = {};
    newuserData[userData.userID] = {"nickName":userData.nickName,"SocketId":socket.id,"colorCode":colorCode,"userImage":userImage};
    allUsers.push(newuserData);
}
```

So this function adds a new Object to array everytime it is called and after calling this function twice with different params i get an array something like this

```
[ { '886': 
     { nickName: 'MOhan',
       SocketId: '9AMRe2v2e-hWuMeBAAAC',
       colorCode: '#d3af07',
       userImage: 'avatar6.jpg' } },
  { '172': 
     { nickName: 'Anil',
       SocketId: 'a5VU5pCzWecMHM2FAAAD',
       colorCode: '#22b913',
       userImage: 'avatar4.jpg' } } ]
```

What i want instead is an object something like this :

```
{ 
   '886': 
     { nickName: 'MOhan',
       SocketId: '9AMRe2v2e-hWuMeBAAAC',
       colorCode: '#d3af07',
       userImage: 'avatar6.jpg' } ,
   '172': 
     { nickName: 'Anil',
       SocketId: 'a5VU5pCzWecMHM2FAAAD',
       colorCode: '#22b913',
       userImage: 'avatar4.jpg' }
}
```

What changes should i make to the code.

Comment: you can get each object from the array, why do you have to change the way you put into array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, objects aren't technically pushed to but instead you define new keys on that object.
Switch your Array for an object literal and just add the key to it.

```
var allUsers = {};
function addObjectToObject(userData) {
    //logic
    allUsers[userData.userId] = newuserData;
}
```

Comment: isn't there missing `newuserData` ?

Comment: @Dwza Yes and no, I omitted all of the logic on purpose :)

Comment: oh, i see... did not realised the `//logic`-comment :D